# How to disable the menu button option in DataGrid MUI?

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

I want to disable the button that pops all the options like: Sort, Filter, Hide, Etc.

[image]

I know you can remove the sorting option in the columns with `sortable: false` and if I want to remove everything else then I can simply use Both of this `disableColumnFilter` to remove the filter and  `disableColumnSelector` to remove pretty much everything else However even if I remove all the options the button is still there and I want to remove it.

[image]

Comment: `disableColumnFilter` didn't work for you? Do you want to remove the button completely or do you only want it to appear disabled (can't click, grey out).

Comment: I found the answer apparently  there are 3 modifiers i'll post in a sec

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I should have done more research before asking but I found the answer after checking for something else.

So you have 3 'modifiers'

- `disableColumnMenu`
- `disableColumnFilter`
- `disableColumnSelector`

`disableColumnMenu` will completely remove the button with the options
`disableColumnFilter` will just remove the filter option
`disableColumnSelector` will remove the hide/show columns

you can check the sort true/false while creating the columns with a simple `sortable = true/false`

Ej:

```
const columns = [
        { field: 'name', headerName: 'Name', width: 450, sortable: true/false}
      ]
```

And this is how it looks with `disableColumnMenu` it doesn't show the button anymore at all

[image]

Comment: Any idea how to disable column menu only for specific columns?

Comment: you can try adding the parameter in the column you want to disable the menu. I'm not sure if that will work though.

Comment: Indeed, adding         disableColumnMenu: true, to column definition object (of type GridColDef) did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same issue regarding having to disable only a single column from being sorted and filtered.

Found the **MUI GridColDef Interface** documentation very helpful: https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/grid-col-def/.

- `sortable`
- `disableColumnMenu`

Answer (score 0):

We can use css to hide the button for columns to display such functionality

```
.MuiDataGrid-columnHeader:not(.MuiDataGrid-columnHeader--sorted) .MuiDataGrid-sortIcon {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
  transition: opacity 200ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
  display: none;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```